# How do I pass a bash script variable to --arg?

Tags: bash, jq

I tried to parse the project sonar database by using a jq if statement with test and regex, like this

```
jq -r 'if (.name | test("\\.example\\.com$")) then . else empty end'
```

and in script form I tried this

```
zcat sonar.json.gz | jq --arg a "$b" -r 'if (.name | test($a)) then . else empty end'
```

while b="\.example\.com$"

(here I actually used sed to create regex from user input).

If I run it I get no output. If I set --arg a "\\.example\\.com$", it works.

Is there a read issue while parsing script variables as regex?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem lies somewhere in the quoting.

You haven't provided sufficient information about your input for a precise answer but here is a simple bash script which runs `jq` using a pattern passed with `--arg` which you can experiment with.  Note the use of single quotes in the assignment to A.

```
#!/bin/bash
A='\.example\.com$'
echo A is $A
jq -M --arg a "$A" 'select(.value | test($a))'
```

Given the following input

```
{ "value": "foo" }
{ "value": "foo.example.com" }
```

It produces

```
A is \.example\.com$
{
  "value": "foo.example.com"
}
```

(note I generally use `-M` to ensure no coloring is added to the output)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDsIgGAZ3nuLzl4R2gO4mDjyAb9AFyK@toWIFjYn67FhNXBzvbjjv8lDretX58dT5BYTdqt7w3U3nyL0JaZJKcBgSLMYMacVxht5Ba3c5wIGkJajMkUNpzM3FK@OJwrk00rWtqvUB@mragPYpEV7iT/12n9uS3w)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash:

```
$ b="\.example\.com$" jq -n 'env.b'
"\\.example\\.com$"

$ b='.example.com$' jq -n 'env.b'
".example.com$"

$ jq -n --arg b '\.example\.com$'  '$b'
"\\.example\\.com$"

$ export b='\.example\.com$'
$ jq -n 'env.b'
"\\.example\\.com$"

$ jq -n --argjson b '".example.com$"' '$b'
".example.com$"
```